# "Fiorellin" or "Fiorellini?"

Tags: word-meaning, single-words, apocope

I was browsing through some of my music CDs, and I found a piece titled "Fiorellin di Siepe" by Raffaele Calace, but in this [collection site](http://www.federmandolino.it/wp/spartiti-music-scores/), it's listed as *Fiorellini* di Siepe. However, if you open the pdf link to the sheet music, it's once again titled "Fiorellin".

As far as I understand, "Fiorellini di Siepe" means "Little Hedge Flowers," right? Does "Fiorellin" mean anything, or is it a typo?

Comment: No, it's a “poetic” way to write eliding the final  vowel, like “amor” for *amore* (love). https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision

Comment: @Hachi The answer box is a little lower :).

Comment: @DenisNardin - yes, but I feel questions about elision have been asked before. I think this is a duplicate.

Comment: I'd add that in general elision is more common for singular forms. That is, _fiorellin_ is more easily interpreted as _fiorellino_, but in poetry or lyrics it may mean _fiorellini_ as well, as here.

Comment: Oh, ok. Forgot to mention that I'm typesetting the score and was wondering which to use in the title. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

It is very common poetic (and musical) usage to drop the last vowel of a word to change the number of syllables of a verse: `Maz-zo-li-no` becomes `maz-zo-lin` (*quel mazzolin di fiori*):

> Amor<*e*>, ch<*e*> a nullo amato amar<*e*> perdona,
>
> mi prese del costui piacer<*e*> sì forte,
>
> che, come vedi, ancor<*a*> non m<*i*> abbandona.

Since the last vowel almost always determines gender and number of something, the elided form is ambiguous and usually considered singular when seen alone, but it depends on the word.

So, *Fiorellin* might mean either *little flower* or *little flowers*.

Answer (score 1):

Putting together an answer from Hachi and DaG's comments:

This is a case of poetic "[elision](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision)". While elision is more common in singular forms, in poetry, it's not unheard of to use elision on a plural form, especially in poetry and song, as in this case.